# Why is git creating read-only (444) files?

Tags: linux, git

Using a shared repo (core.sharedRepository=group) we ran into some issues with git creating read-only (permissions 444) files. No matter which git config items I twiddle there always seems to be some read-only meta-data created on the server side when we push. These files are in .git/ (or objects/ in a bare repo).

Do you really never need to write to these files again (regardless of what git operations you perform)? They may be representative of commit deltas, so really should not be changed, but I was hoping someone could clarify this.

For the inquisitive, the relevant lines look to be 856 and 867 of builtin/index-pack.c in git.

Comment: umask in the ENV correctly set ?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Those files are part of the object database, which really is read-only. No matter what you do with Git, you can't change the *contents* of a specific object once it has been created.

Note that if you back out a commit and create a new one in its place, you'll be creating a *new* object with a *new* identifier and *new* contents. Git will eventually perform its garbage collection to remove the old, unreferenced object(s).

Comment: Thanks, Greg. I was hoping for some references to documentation. Is this reported anywhere in the git docs?

Comment: @Matthew: Here's one reference in the Git wiki: https://git.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Git#Implementation You can find others by searching for "git object database immutable".

Comment: @Greg: If the git object files are read-only (444) how can `$ git gc` remove unreferenced objects? In particular if a third person is running `$ git gc`. I have written a script which checks that everyone in the group can edit files and work with the git repository (doing such things as `git commit --amend`, rewrite git history ....). This scripts sets 775 to files (also the files in .git/config, e.g. index file and the million objects).

Comment: @Hotschke: On Unix, the ability to *remove* a file is determined by the permissions on the file's directory, not the file itself.

Comment: Thanks. I missed this part of unix rights and probably that git objects are only created or deleted never modified.